# Odoo 9 - custom modules

Tags: odoo, windows-10, odoo-9

I am using Odoo 9 and cannot for the life of me figure out how to edit themes/modules.

I have read the documentation - and it says you can add modules to the 'addons' folder - but I cannot find this (I am on windows 10).

Other people said that you can access editing from various places on the frontend. None of these exist on my version. The only app that has editing ability is website via an inline editor.

I tried to change my Administrator's access rights, that handsome devil seems to have them all.

Anybody know how to develop for Odoo 9 on Windows?

Comment: how did you install `odoo`?

Comment: an exacutable - from here https://www.odoo.com/page/download

Comment: check your `C:\ and C:\Users\ProgramFiles(x86)` there should be a folder where the odoo files are stored

Comment: Cool I will check there - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed from an executable - but if you want to make and edit custom modules you need to install from source